# Field 'id' expected a number but got unexpected 'prashant'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get value of user field from my employee model but it's showing above error.I would request your solution to this problem.I have mentioned my models.py & views.py for reference.

`models.py`

```py
    class Employee(models.Model):
        First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)
        Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        DOB = models.DateField()
        Primary_skill=models.TextField(max_length=1000)
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
        Employee_Id = 
    models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False,unique=True)
```

`views.py`

```py
    def loginp(request):

        page ='login'

        if request.method=="POST":
            username = request.POST.get("Username")
            password = request.POST.get("Password")

            name = Employee.objects.get(user=username)
            context={'use':name}


            try:
                username = Employee.objects.get(username=1)

            except:
                messages.error(request,"Invalid Username")

            user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return render(request,'profile.html',context)
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Authentication Failed.Please Try again with correct 
    credentials")
        context={'page':page}
        return render(request,'login.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why taking instance from Employee table?

Instead of this:

```
    name = Employee.objects.get(user=username)
```

Try this:

```
    name = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

And in your `try` block you are accessing `Employee` table with the field `username` , and there is no such field in it so it always goes to `except` block.

There instead of this:

```
    username = Employee.objects.get(username=1)
```

Try this:

```
    username = User.objects.get(username=1)
```

And if your purpose includes if user is included in the `Employee` table, You can try this way too:

```
    name = Employee.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

Answer (score 1):

any relationship by default have id in django but you can access another field using double underscore like (user__username,user__firstname,user__email) etc.

in you case you tried filter user by username but by default User field of Employee model have id so you got an error "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'prashant'"

put like this...

```
name = Employee.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

insted of...

```
name = Employee.objects.get(user=username)
```

Comment: any relationship by default have id in django but you can access another field using double underscore like (user__username,user__firstname,user__email) etc.------Can you provide me link to any document about this

Answer (score 0):

```
name = Employee.objects.get(user=username)
```

here user is foreignkey. it should be int value(ID)
if you want to filter with name then this will work

```
name = Employee.objects.get(user__username=username)
```

But making query in `auth_user` will be much better.